# Uri Constructor .NET Framework Bug?

Tags: c#, .net, uri

Why the thirdRelativeUri fails? Is this a .NET bug? Seems like not fixed in 4.0 either.

```
var googleU = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
var secondRelativeUri = new Uri(googleU,"//test.htm"); // doesn't fail
var thirdRelativeUri = new Uri(googleU,"///test.htm"); // fails - Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

**UPDATE:**

@dariom pointed out that this is because protocol relative URL handling in .NET which make sense however this still seems buggy to me:

```
var thirdRelativeUri = new Uri("///test.htm",UriKind.Relative); // works as expected
var newUri = new Uri(googleU,thirdRelativeUri); //Fails, same error even though it's a relative URI
```

It fails even when the second Uri is `Relative`

Comment: why do you pass "///test.htm" and not "//test.htm" ??

Comment: @DavidePiras cause I'm evil? I need to make the following request: http://example.com///test.htm in a perfect world example.com/test.htm and example.com///test.htm doesn't make a difference but real web servers and frameworks unfortunately are insane and there's thousands of them.

Comment: I agree with @dr.evil. The parsing should accept useless directory/path separators.

Answer (score 5):

The file uri scheme (RFC 1738) file://[host]/path shows that host is optional. ///test.html would mean "Since this usually used for local files the host from RFC 1738 is often empty leading to a starting triple /. [(ref)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes)"

Change **///test.htm** to **file:///test.htm** and the URI constructor will parse it properly. It's `AbsolutePath` will be **/test.html**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the constructor is interpreting **"//test.htm"** as a URI with no scheme and a hostname of **test.htm**. You can see this by examining the value of `secondRelativeUri` - it's **"http://test.htm/"**.

The third URI you're creating is invalid because you have too many slashes.

Comment: As a side note, URIs starting with `//` are called protocol relative URIs.

Comment: Well spotted, still though when I explicitly tell .net it's a relative URI it still doesn't work. Updated the question, added a new code sample.

Answer (score 0):

new Uri(googleU,"//test.htm") mean Uri = http://test.html/    /* valid, Anyway a root somewhere */

new Uri(googleU,"///test.htm") mean Uri = http:///test.html/  /* invalid, Meaningless */

new Uri("///test.htm",UriKind.Relative); //=> Uri = ///test.htm same mistake, not relative location

var r = new Uri("test.htm",UriKind.Relative);

new Uri(googleU, r); // => Uri = http://www.google.com/test.htm

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Even when creating relative URLs, .net treats a string that starts with tow slashes as a host name like in "//example.org/document". Similarly three slahes makes a confusion and an exception is thrown. If you are pretty sure these //test.htm and ///test.htm are paths, then you can try using UriBuilder class.